# Loop for poLCA.table in R (poLCA package)

Tags: r, loops

in `poLCA` package in R I use `poLCA.table` for calculates predicted cell frequencies based on an estimated latent class model.

I need use `poLCA.table` for all combinations of variables in a latent class model

```
data(carcinoma)
f <- cbind(A, B, C, D, E, F, G) ~ 1
lca2 <- poLCA(f, carcinoma, nclass = 2)
poLCA.table(formula = A ~ B, condition = list(), lc = lca2)
```

For example, I need all combinations to A from G.

How can I make it automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This loops creates the 2-way combinations of the letters cast into separate formula objects and then passes each of them to the function you specified:

```
 lapply( apply(combn(LETTERS[1:5],2), 2, 
                  function(col) as.formula( paste(col[1], "~", col[2])  ) ),
         function(x) poLCA.table(formula =x, condition = list(), lc = lca2)
       )
#------------------
[[1]]
          B 1      B 2
A 1 33.572932 18.42707
A 2  5.427068 60.57293

[[2]]
    C 1          C 2
A 1  52 2.551164e-10
A 2  21 4.500000e+01

[[3]]
    D 1          D 2
A 1  52 1.814161e-10
A 2  34 3.200000e+01

[[4]]
          E 1      E 2
A 1 40.408128 11.59187
A 2  6.591872 59.40813

[[5]]
         C 1        C 2
B 1 38.23913  0.7608669
B 2 34.76087 44.2391331

[[6]]
         D 1        D 2
B 1 38.45894  0.5410609
B 2 47.54106 31.4589391

[[7]]
         E 1      E 2
B 1 29.55038  9.44962
B 2 17.44962 61.55038

[[8]]
         D 1       D 2
C 1 65.34774  7.652258
C 2 20.65226 24.347742

[[9]]
           E 1      E 2
C 1 46.0386552 26.96134
C 2  0.9613448 44.03866

[[10]]
          E 1      E 2
D 1 46.316377 39.68362
D 2  0.683623 31.31638
```